# Differentiability of $f$ at $z_0$ implies $f$ is bounded in open neighbourhood of $z_0$

Tags: complex-analysis

> If $f(z)$ is differentiable at $z = z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$, then $f(z)$ is bounded in a neighbourhood of $z_0$.

My attempt: Since $f$ is differentiable at $z_0$, it is continuous at $z_0$. For any $\varepsilon > 0$, we can find a $\delta$-neighbourhood of $z_0$ such that

\begin{align*}
|z - z_0| < \delta &\implies |f(z) - f(z_0)| < \varepsilon \\
&\implies \left| |f(z)| - |f(z_0)| \right| \leq |f(z) - f(z_0)| < \varepsilon\\
&\implies |f(z_0)| - \varepsilon < |f(z)| < |f(z_0)| + \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Taking $\varepsilon = 1$, since $|f(z_0)|$ is finite, we have that $|f(z)|$ is bounded, and hence $f(z)$ is bounded in some neighbourhood of $z_0$.

My question: is the proof above correct? Also, is $f$ being continuous at $z_0$ sufficient to show that $f$ is bounded in a neighbourhood of $z_0$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. And, yes, continuity is enough. A slightly shorter proof would be: take $\delta>0$ such that $|z-z_0|<\delta\implies\bigl|f(z)-f(z_0)\bigr|<1$, and then, if $|z-z_0|<\delta$,\begin{align}\bigl|f(z)\bigr|&=\bigl|f(z)-f(z_0)+f(z_0)\bigr|\\&\leqslant\bigl|f(z)-f(z_0)\bigr|+\bigl|f(z_0)\bigr|\\&<1+\bigl|f(z_0)\bigr|.\end{align}